# About Baking an Object

Tags: rendering

when i render my object, i see it good but when i bake it result is so different as in the pictures below. What may cause it ?

When rendered;[image]

When i bake the texture and check it on the mesh;
[image]

Toatlly different.

Comment: The lower screenshot looks like a basic viewport capture, I see no baking there

Comment: it was the baked texture on mesh. But i replaced it with a more detailed screenshot.